# VLOOKUP for latest non-empty cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vlookup

Basically, I've got the following spreadsheet.

[image]

There are dates along the top. I do a certain amount of past papers each week, and record the highest score I get in a week in cell (paper, week). The column marked Latest Score has the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B17, B17:U17, 12, FALSE)
```

This checks the column of one week. However, as you can see, there are zeros where there isn't a paper for that week. I'd like it so that that VLOOKUP can find the **most recent column in which there is a score** for that row, and return that value in the Latest Score column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506038/getting-the-last-non-empty-cell-in-a-row) should solve your problem.

To quote:

> For numbers get last value with this formula in Z2
>
> `=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,A2:Y2)`
>
> or for text...
>
> `=LOOKUP("zzz",A2:Y2)`
>
> or for either...
>
> `=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:Y2<>""),A2:Y2)`
>
> all the formulas work whether you have blanks in the data or not......